# Runtime error when reading data from a training dataset PyTorch

Tags: python, runtime-error, pytorch, conv-neural-network, training-data

I have a sample of data in my training dataset which I am able to view if I print the data, but when accessing it to train the data, I keep getting `RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Double but got scalar type Float for argument #2 'weight' in call to _thnn_conv2d_forward`. I am unable to figure out why this is happening. I have also attached an image at the end to give a better understanding of the error message.

The labels.txt files looks as follows (name of image linking to another folder with corresponding images, center points (x, y) and radius)

```
0000,   0.67 ,   0.69 ,   0.26 
0001,   0.69 ,   0.33 ,   0.3  
0002,   0.16 ,   0.27 ,   0.15 
0003,   0.54 ,   0.33 ,   0.17 
0004,   0.32 ,   0.45 ,   0.3  
0005,   0.78 ,   0.26 ,   0.17 
0006,   0.44 ,   0.49 ,   0.19
```

EDIT: This is the loss function and optimizer I am using optimizer =

```
optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
```

My validate model function is as follows:

```
def validate_model(model, loader):
    model.eval() # eval mode (batchnorm uses moving mean/variance instead of mini-batch mean/variance)
                  # (dropout is set to zero)

    val_running_loss = 0.0
    val_running_correct = 0

    for int, data in enumerate(loader):
        data, target = data['image'].to(device), data['labels'].to(device)
        output = model(data)
        loss = my_loss(output, target)

        val_running_loss = val_running_loss + loss.item()
        _, preds = torch.max(output.data, 1)

        val_running_correct = val_running_correct+ (preds == target).sum().item()

    avg_loss = val_running_loss/len(loader.dataset)
    val_accuracy = 100. * val_running_correct/len(loader.dataset)

    #----------------------------------------------
    # implementation needed here 
    #----------------------------------------------
    return avg_loss, val_accuracy
```

I have a fit function for working out training loss:

```
def fit(model, train_dataloader):
    model.train()
    train_running_loss = 0.0
    train_running_correct = 0
    for i, data in enumerate(train_dataloader):
        print(data)
        #I believe this is causing the error, but not sure why.
        data, target = data['image'].to(device), data['labels'].to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(data)
        loss = my_loss(output, target)
        train_running_loss = train_running_loss + loss.item()
        _, preds = torch.max(output.data, 1)
        train_running_correct =  train_running_correct + (preds == target).sum().item()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    train_loss = train_running_loss/len(train_dataloader.dataset)
    train_accuracy = 100. * train_running_correct/len(train_dataloader.dataset)

    print(f'Train Loss: {train_loss:.4f}, Train Acc: {train_accuracy:.2f}')

    return train_loss, train_accuracy
```

and the following train_model function which stores the losses and accuracy in a list:

```
train_losses , train_accuracy = [], []
validation_losses , val_accuracy = [], []

def train_model(model,
                optimizer,
                train_loader,
                validation_loader,
                train_losses,
                validation_losses,
                epochs=1):

    """
    Trains a neural network. 
    Args:
        model               - model to be trained
        optimizer           - optimizer used for training
        train_loader        - loader from which data for training comes 
        validation_loader   - loader from which data for validation comes (maybe at the end, you use test_loader)
        train_losses        - adding train loss value to this list for future analysis
        validation_losses   - adding validation loss value to this list for future analysis
        epochs              - number of runs over the entire data set 
    """

    #----------------------------------------------
    # implementation needed here 
    #----------------------------------------------

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        train_epoch_loss, train_epoch_accuracy = fit(model, train_loader)
        val_epoch_loss, val_epoch_accuracy = validate_model(model, validation_loader)
        train_losses.append(train_epoch_loss)
        train_accuracy.append(train_epoch_accuracy)
        validation_losses.append(val_epoch_loss)
        val_accuracy.append(val_epoch_accuracy)

    return
```

And when I run the following code I get the Runtime Error:

```
train_model(model, 
            optimizer,
            train_loader, 
            validation_loader, 
            train_losses, 
            validation_losses,
            epochs=2)
```

> ERROR:  RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Double but got
>   scalar type Float for argument #2 'weight' in call to
>   _thnn_conv2d_forward

Here is a screenshot of the error message as well:
[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cP6mi.png)

EDIT: this is how my model looks like, I am supposed to detect circles in an image with the given centers and radius in the labels.txt file and paint over them - the painting function was given, I had create the model and the training and validation.

```
class CircleNet(nn.Module):    # nn.Module is parent class  
    def __init__(self):
        super(CircleNet, self).__init__()  #calls init of parent class
        #----------------------------------------------
        # implementation needed here 
        #----------------------------------------------
        #keep dimensions of input image: (I-F+2P)/S +1= (128-3+2)/1 + 1 = 128

        #RGB image = input channels = 3. Use 12 filters for first 2 convolution layers, then double
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=12, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=12, out_channels=12, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=12, out_channels=24, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=24, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)

        #Pooling to reduce sizes, and dropout to prevent overfitting
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

        self.drop = nn.Dropout2d(p=0.25)
        self.norm1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(12)
        self.norm2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(24)

        # There are 2 pooling layers, each with kernel size of 2. Output size: 128/(2*2) = 32
        # Have 3 output features, corresponding to x-pos, y-pos, radius. 
        self.fc = nn.Linear(in_features=32 * 32 * 32, out_features=3)

    def forward(self, x):
        """
        Feed forward through network
        Args:
            x - input to the network

        Returns "x", which is the network's output
        """

        #----------------------------------------------
        # implementation needed here 
        #----------------------------------------------
        #Conv1
        out = self.conv1(x)
        out = self.pool(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.norm1(out)
        #Conv2
        out = self.conv2(out)
        out = self.pool(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.norm1(out)
        #Conv3
        out = self.conv3(out)
        out = self.drop(out)
        #Conv4
        out = self.conv4(out)
        out = F.dropout(out, training=self.training)
        out = out.view(-1, 32 * 32 * 32)
        out = self.fc(out)


        return out
```

EDIT: Should it help here is my custom loss function:

```
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

def my_loss(outputs, labels):

    """
    Args:
        outputs - output of network ([batch size, 3]) 
        labels  - desired labels  ([batch size, 3])
    """

    loss = torch.zeros(1, dtype=torch.float, requires_grad=True)
    loss = loss.to(device)

    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

    #----------------------------------------------
    # implementation needed here 
    #----------------------------------------------

    # Observe: If you need to iterate and add certain values to loss defined above
    # you cannot write: loss +=... because this will raise the error: 
    # "Leaf variable was used in an inplace operation"
    # Instead, to avoid this error write: loss = loss + ...       

    return loss
```

Train Loader (given to me):

```
train_dir      = "./train/"
validation_dir = "./validation/"
test_dir       = "./test/"


train_dataset = ShapesDataset(train_dir)

train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, 
                          batch_size=32,
                          shuffle=True)



validation_dataset = ShapesDataset(validation_dir)

validation_loader = DataLoader(validation_dataset, 
                               batch_size=1,
                               shuffle=False)



test_dataset = ShapesDataset(test_dir)

test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, 
                          batch_size=1,
                          shuffle=False)


print("train loader examples     :", len(train_dataset)) 
print("validation loader examples:", len(validation_dataset))
print("test loader examples      :", len(test_dataset))
```

EDIT: This view image, target circle labels and network output was also given:

```
"""
View first image of a given number of batches assuming that model has been created. 
Currently, lines assuming model has been creatd, are commented out. Without a model, 
you can view target labels and the corresponding images.
This is given to you so that you may see how loaders and model can be used. 
"""

loader = train_loader # choose from which loader to show images
bacthes_to_show = 2
with torch.no_grad():
    for i, data in enumerate(loader, 0): #0 means that counting starts at zero
        inputs = (data['image']).to(device)   # has shape (batch_size, 3, 128, 128)
        labels = (data['labels']).to(device)  # has shape (batch_size, 3)
        img_fnames = data['fname']            # list of length batch_size

        #outputs = model(inputs.float())
        img = Image.open(img_fnames[0])

        print ("showing image: ", img_fnames[0])

        labels_str = [ float(("{0:.2f}".format(x))) for x in labels[0]]#labels_np_arr]

        #outputs_np_arr = outputs[0] # using ".numpy()" to convert tensor to numpy array
        #outputs_str = [ float(("{0:.2f}".format(x))) for x in outputs_np_arr]
        print("Target labels :", labels_str )
        #print("network coeffs:", outputs_str)
        print()
        #img.show()

        if (i+1) == bacthes_to_show:
            break
```

Here is the output I'm getting, it is supposed to cover the full circle:
[Output I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbKJm.png)
Any idea will be helpful.

Comment: From the stack trace, it looks like your data should be a float and it's a double instead. Can you try setting `data` to `data['image'].to(device).float()`, and do the same thing with `target`?

Comment: @kimbo I did try that, and then I get the same error except that it expects a type Long but found float. `RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Long but got scalar type Float for argument #2 'target' in call to _thnn_nll_loss_forward`

Comment: Try to taking off the `.float()` on the target

Comment: @kimbo Nope, getting the same error unfortunately, about expected Long but got type Float

Comment: Your original error was getting raised when you ran `model(data`). What does your model look like?

Comment: I initially used keys - `data[0], data[1]` to get the information instead of specifying `data['image'] or data['labels']` but then I kept getting `KeyError: 0`

Comment: @kimbo I have edited the question and added code for my model

Comment: Sorry, meant to make that a comment, not an answer. Must've pressed the wrong button

Comment: Was the line `#outputs = model(inputs.float())` commented out when you got it? And does that line work?

Comment: @kimbo sorry, internet was down. But yes, the line was commented out when I got the file, didn't want to temper with given code.

Comment: @kimbo So I changed the following line in the fit function `output = model(data.float())` and then got the following error: `RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (32) must match the size of tensor b (3) at non-singleton dimension 1`

Answer (score 0):

I basically added(in the validate_model and fit function) this:

```
 _, target= torch.max(target.data, 1)
```

below the  `_, preds = torch.max(output.data, 1)` line of code to get the data and target to be of the same length. Also changed the loss function from `CrossEntropyLoss` to `MSELoss`

Then in the same functions:
I changed the following line `output = model(data)` to `output = model(data.float())`

Comment: @kimbo Yup. But I got one more issue, and that is I'm still not getting the desired ouput. It does paint the circle, but not on top of the existing one. I think it is the my_ loss function. I added the Output Image in my question